# Make Git Tag visible in repo

Tags: git, repository, tagging, git-tag

Hi I recently started with Git. I want to tag previous commit with version. Sequence of steps which i followed:

```
git checkout Xerxes   //to that specific commit
git tag version-name   // tagging with the name
git checkout mainline  //
```

But i cant see the tag in the repository. When I do git tag, tag name is getting displayed. How can I display the tag with that specific commit in the repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to push tag by using git push --tags

Answer (score 0):

`git checkout HEAD^` will checkout the previous commit. To tag that commit in one command, without having to checkout the branch, `git tag <options> HEAD^` will do it.

```
$ git tag -a 1.0.0 -m "Version 1.0.0" HEAD^
```

The above creates an annotated tag "1.0.0" with message "Version 1.0.0" on the previous commit.

```
o- commit 4 (master)
|- commit 3 <1.0.0> Version 1.0.0
|- commit 2
+- commit 1
```